# Redundant [] when transpose a matrix ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml, computer-science

I'm testing my functions for transposing a matrix(`type matrix = float list list`) in OCaml, here's my code:

```
(* get the first column of the matrix *)
let rec get_column (a: matrix): float list = 
    match a with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs ->
      (match x with
      | [] -> []
      | h :: t -> h :: get_column xs)

(* get the rest of the element in the matrix *)
let rec get_tail (a: matrix): matrix =
  match a with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
    (match x with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> t :: get_tail xs)

(* find the transpose of a matrix *)
let rec transpose (lss : matrix) : matrix =
  match lss with
  | [] -> []
  | _ -> get_column lss :: transpose (get_tail lss)
```

When I tested it out, there's a redundant `[]` at the very end and I don't why.
So for example, the output of:

```
transpose[[0.; 4.; 8.]; [1.; 5.; 9.]; [2.; 6.; 10.]; [3.; 7.; 11.]]
```

should be

```
[[0.; 1.; 2.; 3.]; [4.; 5.; 6.; 7.]; [8.; 9.; 10.; 11.]]
```

But my code output is:

```
[[0.; 1.; 2.; 3.]; [4.; 5.; 6.; 7.]; [8.; 9.; 10.; 11.]; []]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can simplify your pattern matching significantly.

```
let rec get_column (a: matrix): float list = 
  match a with
  | [] | []::_ -> []
  | (h::_)::xs -> h :: get_column xs

let rec get_tail (a: matrix): matrix =
  match a with
  | [] | []::_ -> []
  | (_::t)::xs -> t :: get_tail xs
```

Having done that, let's look at how a simple call to transpose is evaluated.

```
transpose [[1.; 2.]; [3.; 4.]]
[1.; 3.] :: transpose [[2.]; [4.]]
[1.; 3.] :: [2.; 4.] :: transpose [[]; []]
[1.; 3.] :: [2.; 4.] :: [] :: transpose []
[1.; 3.] :: [2.; 4.] :: [] :: []
[[1.; 3.]; [2.; 4.]; []]
```

Essentially what you're doing is getting the head of every list. This can be done with `List.map` (you can implement your own version if you must).

```
let get_column lss =
  List.(map hd lss)
```

Your `get_tail` function is basically just:

```
let get_tail lss =
  List.(map tl lss)
```

For every element in the first row, you want to retrieve each column.

```
let rec transpose lss =
  match lss with
  | []::_ | [] -> []
  | (h::t)::xs -> 
    let heads = h :: List.(map hd xs) in
    let tails = t :: List.(map tl xs) in
    heads :: transpose tails
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of bugs, you should test the simplest case that exhibits the issue. In your case, that would be `transpose [[0.]]`. Since the example is very small, you can trace the execution of your `transpose` function by hand and catch the issue.